# Why was my Steam WINE question closed as off-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I recently asked this question [Why does Steam require a new installation in Wine for every game?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/673698/why-does-steam-require-a-new-installation-in-wine-for-every-game), but I have just noticed that it has been closed as 'off-topic', but I asked a few mods and other people why people were VTCing it, and they said that it looked fine and they didn't know why people were VTCing it...

So now finally it has been closed as off-topic, and I don't really mind too much as I got my answer, and don't need any more answers, however if people look at it in the future it might put them off asking similar questions about Steam and WINE which may not be good as I think that all these things in regard to Ubuntu are fine and on-topic here as stated in the [help center](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) in regard to third-party applications.

So now to get to my real point, why was this closed as off-topic? Because I, and many other people, don't see it, so some clarification of this would be nice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*I* voted to close as *unclear what you're asking*, whose description reads:

> Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to
>   highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard
>   to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://meta.askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help
>   clarifying this question.

And I did ask for clarification: Where did you hear this nonsense?

Your response was: somewhere in chat. And that is clearly not clarification, it says **nothing** about the context.

Further, you say:

> Also, I have heard mixed input in this area so please correct me if I am wrong on anything.

What mixed input did you hear exactly? Where did you hear it from? Are we we supposed to probe your mind?